# Parameter comparison in dataset

Tags: parameters

I am passing a parameter from one SSRS report to another SSRS report.
I want to generate a dynamic dataset based on this parameter value.

I have generated a dynamic dataset where column27 contains values like

1. "View"
2. "Common"

then My paramater contains a table name like

1. abcd.***view***.dbo.abcde
2. btcd.***common***.dbo.fgfg

Now, inside my dataset, in SELECT query, I want to check if the parameter contains value in column27. but, I am not able to do this.

something like

select * from
@parameter 
where @parameter contains column27

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CHARINDEX** to check for the value of the column in your parameter string:

```
WHERE CHARINDEX (column27, @parameter) > 0
```

I haven't tried using a parameter for a table name so I'm not sure if that's going to work like you want it to.

```
select * from @parameter
```